# Checkout flow: how should I process a new order?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to build an App which allows the customer to download a custom document after his order (so, the product I'm selling it's a digital custom document in pdf).

I'm trying to build that using React for the frontend, Node and Express for the backend, and PayPal Express Checkout (full-stack implementation) as payment.

What is not clear to me is **what steps I should take to process an order**.

I'm a this point:

1. Once customer clicks on PayPal button on client side it starts a call on `http://localhost/api/paypal/orders` endpoint which create the order on the Paypal side and return the PayPal order ID (e.g. `id12345`)
2. After the customer approves the payment on the PayPal popup, the client starts a call on `http://localhost/api/paypal/orders/id12345/capture` endpoint

then? What other endpoints should I crete on the server and what they should return? Maybe... 1 for save the actual store order on my MongoDB and the transaction details, 1 for create the invoice for the order, 1 for allowing the product download ???

**Could you please clarify what steps I need to take, what are the endpoints I should create, and what each endpoints should return?**

---

Maybe something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do too many things in too many routes. just create a route called something like `process-order` then you could have an async controller of that route which would contain separate functions for

1. Storing the order details in mongodb.
2. Create an invoice
3. Send a token that allows access to download page.

first , just `await` the function to complete then call the next.

```
exports.processOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
  const newOrder = await Order.create({
    order: req.params.id,
    details: req.body.details
  })
  
  const createInvoice = () => {
    return newOrder._id;
  }
  const invoice = createInvoice();
  
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
       invoiceId = newOrder._id,
    },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: '24h'
    }
   );
    return res.status(200).json({status: 'success', message: 'you have 24 hours to download your digital goods', token})
  
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error)
}
}
```

This is a very basic idea, but basically store all of your info in one controller, then send a token with the id of the invoice, then when they go to download the book you would have a route where you verify the token. If it succeeds then the book is sent. like this:

```
app.use(
  '/book-download',
  expressJwt({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET, algorithms: ['HS256'] })
);

app.get('/book-download/success', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const invoiceId = req.user.invoiceId;
    const invoice = await Invoice.find({_id: invoiceId})
    if (invoice) {
      return res.status(200).json({status: 'success', message: 'congratulations on your new download', data: {E-book})
    } else {
      return.res.status(404).json({status: 'fail', message: 'could not find an invoice with that ID'})
  } catch (error) {
    return res.send(error)
    }
});
```

You can choose to send the pdf via express, or you can allow them to enter a certain part of the website if the return is valid. There you go, that's an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, do I have to create just 1 route for all of this and process all steps on the server? However, since I'm using the Full-Stack implementation of `PayPal Express Checkout` I'm forced to create at least 2 routes: 1 for `create` the order on PayPal side which returns the PayPal order ID and 1 for `capture` passing this latter. First of all you recommend I use the `Model-Routes-Controllers-Services` pattern, don't you? Then you recommend I develop all the logic at the capture route time, right?

Comment: In order to download the digital product I have arranged another route which returns an url for the client. The client puts that url in a `<a download href={url}>Download</a>` tag which allows the customer to download it.

Comment: Yes I recommend one route for handling the request. It’s fine if PayPal needs it’s own.

Comment: My concern about this approach is… what if tomorrow I need to implement a new payment type? However, could you please list more in deep the logical steps (not the code) I need to take for the whole process starting from the PayPal button click on client side?

Comment: adding more payment types is exactly why this approach is better, you can process the payment then send it to `processOrder` which will process the information you just received from your new payment type. It's reusable. createOrder -> processOrder -> send token -> allow user to download using token.

Comment: Thanks but, as you probably understand, I have a lot of mess in my head. Could you please help me structure the app correctly on this codesanbox ( https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-khorana-ncf9m2?file=/index.js )?

Answer (score 0):

In Express check out, you need to define success / cancel handler

Ref here : https://www.section.io/engineering-education/nodejs-paypal-checkout/

In the success handler, based on the returned URI => you will get a Payer ID and payment ID. Based on that retrieve the transactio information (that internally contains yours order ID). Update your Order id as scucess / cancelled based on the paypal response.

```
app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
  const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

  const execute_payment_json = {
    "payer_id": payerId,
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        }
    }]
  };

// Obtains the transaction details from paypal
  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
      //When error occurs when due to non-existent transaction, throw an error else log the transaction details in the console then send a Success string reposponse to the user.
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
        res.send('Success');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the PayPal Express Checkout implementation is working. I followed the Full-stack steps on the official docs here ( https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ ). Why should I use the `paypal-rest-sdk`? Isn't that deprecated or I'm wrong?